# BigQuery: Delete records from subselect caused by table join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**The Problem**

So I've collected some rows doing a join and I need to delete these rows with a query. Does anyone know how to form that delete query? I know it sounds easy but can't find a way.

**The code**

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
           entity_key, min(actual_posting_time) as min_time
        FROM 
            myTable
        WHERE 
            _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2018-12-01") AND TIMESTAMP("2018-12-04")
        GROUP BY
            entity_key
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) >= 2 
        )t1
    LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT entity_key, actual_posting_time
        FROM 
            myTable 
        WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2018-12-01") AND TIMESTAMP("2018-12-04")
        ) t2
    ON t1.entity_key  = t2.entity_key
  AND min_time <> t2.actual_posting_time )
```

So from the subselect above I want to delete each and every record I have in myTable. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Which subquery? You have two.

Comment: @RyanWilson the outcome of this join is the one I'm interested into deleting.

Comment: A `DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE entity_key IN (Your example query)` should do except you would change the outer most query to only select `entity_key` and not `*`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't...entity_key is not a unique thing and I only need to delete the duplicate records in the timestamps specified as the subquery indicates. So if I do what you're suggesting it will delete more records than desired.

Comment: Is there any column that is unique?

Comment: @RyanWilson unfortuantely not...I'm thinking something like combining entity_key with actual_posting_time but my sql knowledge is not that sharp

Comment: Yeah, I work in SQL-Server so some of what exists there doesn't appear to exist for bigquery, I think you could do as you said to create unique column values for each record, I could provide you with some help on that if that is what you decide.

Comment: @RyanWilson please do sir

Comment: Do you need to run a query to add the new column or can you do it through a designer mode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190321/discussion-between-catchiecop-and-ryan-wilson).

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55238277/1031958)  which is a very similar question

Comment: @TamirKlein this is about appending...I need to delete records

Comment: Yes merge command does insert, update and delete which is very cool. I suggest you check it out more closely.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the query, you want to keep the oldest record of the rows with same entity_key. In this case, you can just `CONCAT` the both fields, something like this:

```
DELETE * FROM myTable 
WHERE CONCAT(CAST(entity_key as string), '_', CAST(actual_posting_time as string)) 
NOT IN (
    SELECT 
       CONCAT(CAST(entity_key as string), '_', CAST(min(actual_posting_time) as min_time)
    FROM 
        myTable
    WHERE 
        _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2018-12-01") AND TIMESTAMP("2018-12-04")
        AND entity_key IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        entity_key
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) >= 2 
)
```

The second condition of WHERE clause in the sub query is for due to the semantics of `NOT IN` with standard SQL as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#not_in_conditions_and_null). Playing with some public dataset, you can see the result that will be deleted by using select command:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_service_requests` 
WHERE CONCAT(CAST(complaint_type as string), '_',CAST(status_change_date as string)) NOT IN (
    SELECT CONCAT(CAST(complaint_type as string), '_',CAST(min(status_change_date) as string))
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_service_requests`
    WHERE complaint_type is not null
    GROUP BY complaint_type
)
```

Another way to achieve this should be using `EXISTS`, something like this:

```
#standardSQL
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT complaint_type, MIN(status_change_date) AS min_date
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_service_requests`
  GROUP BY complaint_type )
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_service_requests` AS t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM t1
  WHERE t1.complaint_type = t2.complaint_type
    AND t1.min_date = t2.status_change_date 
)
```

Notice that with this public table, the results differ a little bit because there are rows with `status_change_date` as `NULL`. These ones are not removed by `NOT IN` but yes by `NOT EXISTS`.